# how to make header title with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

there is a ionic framework in which it is too easy to make header title  with two left and right buttons and it is responsive.In other words header title always in middle of page .

here is code how they implement ..here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/BqtvCYYfhhbokzbbOXU4?p=preview

[image]

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

But same thing I need to implement using only HTML5 and css3 or css I tried but I am not able to set my button position  left and right .how to set button position left and right .

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/OGr7px9jueIfDTsHhePA?p=preview

```
<body>
  <div style="" class="header">
     <button style="position:absolute;left:5px">left</button>
   <h2 style="margin:0px;padding-top:10px;color:white">Title !</h2> 
   <button style="position:absolute;right:5px">right</button>
</div>
 </body>
```

**css**

```
.header{
  background:blue;
  height:44px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The h2 is forcing the button to move down because it forces a line break, just rearrange the order like this:

```
<div style="" class="header">
   <button style="position:absolute;left:5px">left</button>
   <button style="position:absolute;right:5px">right</button>
   <h2 style="margin:0px;padding-top:10px;color:white">Title !</h2> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the 2nd button above the `H2` and add `top: 2px` (or something you need) to both buttons' style. They need a `top`-rule, otherwise the 2nd gets displayed after the `H2` like now.